# Combine regional netcdf file to one global file?

Tags: netcdf

I have 9 NC files, corresponding to 9 regions of the world, where longitude is divided by 60, latitude is divided by 120, how can I combine the above 9 files into one global file?

Have tried CDO mergegrid, but can only merge 2 files at a time, is there a way to merge 9 files at a time?

Answer (score 2):

`cdo mergegrid` is likely the wrong operation for this. You want to try `collgrid` instead. It sounds like you have the world split into 3x3 equally sized rectangles. Combining these is exactly what `collgrid` is designed to do. The command should be something like:

```
cdo collgrid *infile.nc outfile.nc
```

See page 45 of the user guide for more details https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much. Isee this command and I guess this only can merge on one coord. You mean it can merge longtitude and latitude at one time?

Comment: Another question: what happens to if there are duplicate longitude value? like 120?

Comment: Have you tried using it with your data? Are you getting problems?